# Should I send fetch request on each keystroke or store the json data already in json file?

Tags: api, flutter

Hey I am using an api to retrieve json data in my flutter app. An api gives me the response like that and results array contains about 800 objects :

```
{
  "response": "success",
  "results-for": "abcd",
  "results": [
    {
     "name":"value",
    },
    {
     "name":"value",
    },
    .
    .
    .
    . 
]
```

So I just want to ask should I send fetch request on each keystroke to the api or should I store the json data in json file locally which I retrived already from the api.

I want to show the "name" key as my dropdown options in my app which api returned to me....

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you should avoid making unnecessary calls to the API.

Also generally speaking you shouldn't make API calls on every keystroke. Having a minimum character limit (ex:3) is good, but beside that you should also implement a timer that waits for the user to make a break in typing and then make an API call. Like if a new character isn't typed in for over 300-500ms make an API call, if a new keystroke does appear reset the timer. Why that much time: [link1](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/38545) , [link2](https://userinterfaces.aalto.fi/typing37k/).

All that being said you didn't provide enough information to give you a conclusive answer for this particular case. I don't know how the API in question works... there are some cases when you just can't pre-fetch the results, here are a few them:

- If the API has a limit on how many results it returns then yes, you should keep fetching until the result set is lower than the limit.
- If the DB from which the API is getting those results is updated frequently and it is vital that your users always see the latest results then you should keep fetching.
- If the SQL behind the API doesn't do wildcard searches, like if it has to be an exact match.

If I understood you correctly the result set has ~800 objects in total, I personally would fetch that once and then filter it from my end. You save bandwidth, you put less strain on the server, you get better user experience: faster and more reliable than making many api calls that might or might not go through if the user's internet connection is spotty.
*EDIT*: that is if I knew for sure that data set isn't going to grow much, otherwise min. character limit: 3 & wait for user to stop typing (timer, 300ms) before making API calls.

Comment: Hey I am using superhero api and in the TextField say user type   ' bat '  then I want to show all the result related to 'bat' like  'batman' , 'batgirl'  etc which is already provided by api and I have nothing to do with that ...... I just want to show the all related result in my dropdown so that user can select from it.......

Comment: https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/10217870509586417/search/bat   check it out for more details.   Just want to show bat related all searches as dropdown so that user can select from it

Comment: Well from what I see you can't get all the results at once, gotta submit at least one character for the API to give a response. You could go alphabetically (/search/name/a to /search/name/z) and pre-fetch everything, but that would be inconvenient because the API SQL query looks like %search%, so you would end up with duplicates which you would have to filter out. Anyhow for this case I would probably just put a min. character limit of 3 and that delay (wait for user to stop typing) before making an API call.

Comment: https://cdn.rawgit.com/akabab/superhero-api/0.2.0/api/all.json, here all the response from api is present. what your opinion about it. Should I store it locally?

Comment: Oh nice, there is a complete set. Then yeah I would certainly store this locally, new superheroes don't appear that often and they don't change their attributes often either :).